# Injecting <meta> and <link> tags?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Does anyone know how to use the `html-webpack-plugin` to do injection of `<link>` and `<meta>` tags pointing to files?

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Comment: Can you try defining a custom template? Copy/paste their original, point to that, and do the tweaks necessary.